# \<C-v> character in vim

Tags: keyword

I've this in my vimrc

```
let g:currentmode={
            \ 'n'      : 'NORMAL  ',
            \ 'v'      : 'VISUAL  ',
            \ 'V'      : 'V·Line  ',
            \ '^V' : 'V·Block ',
            \ 'i'      : 'INSERT  ',
            \ 'R'      : 'REPLACE ',
            \ 'c'      : 'COMMAND ',
            \ 't'      : 'TERM    '
            \}

set statusline=
            \%{toupper(g:currentmode[mode()])}
            \\ %{&filetype!=#''?&filetype:'none'}
            \\ \ %{&fileformat==#'unix'?'U':&fileformat==#'dos'?'D':'N'}
            \:%{&readonly\|\|!&modifiable?&modified?'%*':'%%':&modified?'**':'--'}
            \\ \ %{expand('%:~:.')!=#''?expand('%:~:.'):'[No\ Name]'}
            \%=\ %3p%%\ \ %l:\ %3c
```

The character that you see as the key in the currentmode dictionary for the value `V.Block` is something I inserted by pressing `<C-v><C-v`, but here it shows up as a box, so I changed it into `^V` for the sake of visibility here in the forum. I don't want a keyword like that in my vimrc, is there any way I can change it into something like `<C-v>`? I've tried `\<C-v>`, and `<C-v>`, doesn't work either of these.

Comment: "...here it shows up as ." Shows up as what?  And then,  "...any way I can change it into something?"  Something? A set of car keys? A top hat? What _exactly_ do you want to change it into?

Comment: " here it shows up as ." was not my fault. When I wrote the question vi.stackexchange showed me a box, then after posting the question it disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the single-quotes you are using. Single quotes enclose "literal-strings", in these strings, the backslash is not a escape character, but just a backslash.

You could use double-quotes like `"\<C-v>"`. Just try the following two commands:

```
:echo '\<C-v>'
:echo "\<C-v>"
```

You might want to read `:help string` and `:help literal-string`.

Comment: I knew about literal-strings and strings, but didn't occur to me in this case!